# How does TensorBoard profile plugin parse *.xplane.pb output?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Started profile on training model by following this on the tutorial:
`tf.profiler.experimental.client.trace('grpc://localhost:6009','gs://your_tb_logdir', 2000)`
This generates a profile output: localhost_6009.xplane.pb.
How does this single binary file eventually be parsed into multiple data files that could be parsed by different tools?
Thanks.